# PHP How can I get HEX Color code from array of R + G + B?

Tags: php, html, hex, rgb

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [red] => 252
    [green] => 168
    [blue] => 166
    [alpha] => 0
)
```

It's an output of function **imagecolorsforindex**. 
How can I get a HTML code from these elements? For example: #99CCFF

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can't, since alpha is not supported. But since the alpha is 0, we can assume that it won't matter. As such, pass each value into [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with a format specifier of `%02x` for each element.

```
c = sprintf('#%02x%02x%02x', val['red'], val['green'], val['blue']);
```

Comment: about alpha: See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color with that: `color: rgba(0-255, 0-255, 0-255, 0-1);` is no problem. And some browsers already interpret this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Convert RGB from/to HTML hex color](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_convert_rgb_from_to_html_hex_color.xml)

```
rgb2html($array[0], $array[1], $array[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function contributed in the comments of [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#93835) of the PHP manual.

```
<?PHP

function rgb2hex2rgb($c){
   if(!$c) return false;
   $c = trim($c);
   $out = false;
  if(preg_match("/^[0-9ABCDEFabcdef\#]+$/i", $c)){
      $c = str_replace('#','', $c);
      $l = strlen($c) == 3 ? 1 : (strlen($c) == 6 ? 2 : false);

      if($l){
         unset($out);
         $out[0] = $out['r'] = $out['red'] = hexdec(substr($c, 0,1*$l));
         $out[1] = $out['g'] = $out['green'] = hexdec(substr($c, 1*$l,1*$l));
         $out[2] = $out['b'] = $out['blue'] = hexdec(substr($c, 2*$l,1*$l));
      }else $out = false;

   }elseif (preg_match("/^[0-9]+(,| |.)+[0-9]+(,| |.)+[0-9]+$/i", $c)){
      $spr = str_replace(array(',',' ','.'), ':', $c);
      $e = explode(":", $spr);
      if(count($e) != 3) return false;
         $out = '#';
         for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
            $e[$i] = dechex(($e[$i] <= 0)?0:(($e[$i] >= 255)?255:$e[$i]));

         for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
            $out .= ((strlen($e[$i]) < 2)?'0':'').$e[$i];

         $out = strtoupper($out);
   }else $out = false;

   return $out;
}

?>

Output

#FFFFFF =>
 Array{
   red=>255,
   green=>255,
   blue=>255,
   r=>255,
   g=>255,
   b=>255,
   0=>255,
   1=>255,
   2=>255
 }


#FFCCEE =>
 Array{
   red=>255,
   green=>204,
   blue=>238,
   r=>255,
   g=>204,
   b=>238,
   0=>255,
   1=>204,
   2=>238
 }
CC22FF =>
 Array{
   red=>204,
   green=>34,
   blue=>255,
   r=>204,
   g=>34,
   b=>255,
   0=>204,
   1=>34,
   2=>255
 }

0 65 255 => #0041FF
255.150.3 => #FF9603
100,100,250 => #6464FA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple piece of code below.

```
$rgb = (123,222,132);
$rgbarr = explode(",",$rgb,3);
echo sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $rgbarr[0], $rgbarr[1], $rgbarr[2]);
```

This will return #7bde84